# InstallShield 2010 SQL Script multi line comment bug?

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010, installshield-2009

I think I found a bug with multi-line comments and SQL scripts in InstallShield 2010.

To reproduce the bug, create a basic MSI project. Go to Installation Designer -> SQL Scripts, create a SQL connection then add a new script that contains the following script:

```
/*
USE [master]
GO
*/

USE master
GO
```

Build the MSI and try to install it, you will receive the following MSI error:

> Error 27506.Error executing SQL script sqlscript.sql. Line 3. Missing
>   end comment mark '*/'. (113)

Changing the multi-line comment to -- form will solve the issue. Also, if the end comment mark is not being preceded by a GO statement, the install will not fail. For instance:

```
/*
THIS
WILL
NOT
FAIL
*/
```

Has someone experienced this bug? Any way to "fix" it?

PS: I'll be posting this to Flexara's forum.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like known behavior to me. I believe the parsing looks for lines of `GO` without respect to anything else, so multi-line comments do not affect it. See hidenori's second response on the thread [Install Shield is trashing SQL Scripts](http://community.installshield.com/archive/index.php?t-137389.html).

You appear to have already identified the workaround - change the `GO` to a `--GO`.

Comment: Yup. But the workaround is unacceptable because the SQL files are being generated by an O/R mapping tool.

Comment: Seems odd that a tool would generate commented sections. Can you fix the tool? Or change the separator from `GO` to something else?

Comment: There are no options to turn off the comments on generated code. Worst case, I think I'll need to write a scrubber to clean the generated script. BTW, the tool is LLBLGen. I think its quite popular.